# Parallel threads break up

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I've written a non-static class.

Within this class, there is a non-static method that calls a static method of the same class.
Within this static method, 2 or more different threads are started in anonymous methods (or lambda expressions....) that do some work on a very large array independently.

This works all perfectly !! Great performance, no problems.....

But....there is also a public static property that is protected by a static locking object...that I do not use for any other purpose than for locking this static property.

All together looks somehow like this:

```cs
public class testClass
{
    private volatile static bool cancelProcessing;
    private static readonly object lockObj = new object();

    public static bool CancelProcessing
    {
        get
        {
            lock (lockObj)
            {return cancelProcessing;}
        }
        set
        {
            lock (lockObj)
            {cancelProcessing = value;}
        }
    }

    public void callingMethod()
    {
        staticThreadsMethods();
    }

    private static void staticThreadsMethods()
    {
         int parts = 4; // array parts
         CountdownEvent _countdown = new CountdownEvent(parts);
         for (int u = 0; u < parts; u++)
            {
                Threads[u] = delegate(object counter)
                {
                    // array gets processed
                    _countdown.Signal();
                };
         }

         _countdown.Wait();
    }
}
```

after calling `callingMethod()`, 2 or e.g 4 or more threads are started at the same time as anonymous delegates (or lambda expression) within `staticThreadsMethods()`...

Now, what I really cannot understand is the following:

Do I change the value of the a property `CancelProcessing` from another thread, while all threads are running in parallel, although this property is not used within the threads (it should have been used to cancel the threads, but I had always the same error/exceptions), I get a System.AccessViolationException because the unsafe pointer to the array 'cannot be dereferenced...The pointer is not valid' anymore (??) when I just change the property value, but do nothing else than that....  Why is that?

Comment: you might want to have a look at that http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: the end of your question in particular is difficult to follow: you should start by stating all the facts properly, and then ask your questions by refering to the relevant facts if necessary.

Comment: Yes, you are right....  I will consider your comments next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4 and above, I recommend using Tasks instead of threads for your compute bound array processing. Use CancellationTokenSource for cancellation.
About the exception it probably got to do with your array processing and not with the bool or locking. You have to reveal more about the array processing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (!!!) - I know about Tasks and the CancellationTokenSource, but I wanted to do it that way first, to verify my code is working so far....  and to keep it more simple.... maybe be able to write it for Linux as well...  But you are absolutely right! The reference to the array gets `null` when I'm cancelling my thread because the form that interacts with the class gets closed, therefore I get this exception !! - Thank you so much, you saved my day ! :)